# After moving the moodledata folder, the contents are inaccessible

Tags: moodle

On my server I have the folder "moodledata". After removing the folder, my moodle had the following error:

> Fatal error: $CFG->dataroot is not configured properly, directory does
>   not exist or is not accessible! Exiting.

Then I returned to again put the folder on the server. But now the files submitted by users are inaccessible.

I am referring here ace profile pictures, the logo of the site Moodle, or content placed in the disciplines, pdf files, all files uploaded by other users.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have changed the permission value for dataFolder to 0777, but is the change recursive ?

that might fix the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Its probably the folder permissions.

```
chmod -R 0777 /path/to/moodledata
```

https://docs.moodle.org/29/en/Installing_Moodle#Create_the_.28moodledata.29_data_directory

You might also need to change the owner but this depends on how the web server is set up. You will need to find the web server user. This is just an example:

```
chown -R www-data:www-data /path/to/moodledata
```

Comment: I've changed the folder permissions to the value 0777. But the problem persists.For example, the logo of the site has this address: ".../pluginfile.php?file=%2F1%2Ftheme_elegance%2Flogo%2F1443619225%2Flogo.png", but not show. *I have Moodle on a web server, so I can not do linux commands.